# How can I get all column names matching a given string in Sybase?

Tags: sap-iq

I've searched for a bit but wasn't able to find a specific question on this. How do I obtain all the column names in a table whose names contain a specific string? Specifically, if the column name satisfies `like %bal%` then I would like to write a query that would return that column name and others that meet that criteria in Sybase.

**Edit**: The Sybase RDBMS is Sybase IQ.

Comment: @markp-fuso Its Sybase IQ. I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on OPs additional comments re: question is for a Sybase IQ database.

---

I don't have a Sybase IQ database in front of me at the moment but we should be able to piece together a workable query based on IQ's system tables/views:

- [IQ system views](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1270/html/iqref/X201559.htm)
- [IQ system tables](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1270/html/iqref/X201559.htm)

The easier query will use the system view `SYSCOLUMNS`:

```
select  cname
from    SYS.SYSCOLUMNS
where   tname = '<table_name>'
and     cname like '%<pattern_to_match>%'
```

Or going against the system tables `SYSTABLE` and `SYSCOLUMN`:

```
select  c.column_name
from    SYS.SYSTABLE t
join    SYS.SYSCOLUMN c
on      t.table_id = c.table_id
where   t.table_name = '<table_name>'
and     c.column_name like '%<pattern_to_match>%'
```

**NOTE**: The Sybase ASE query (below) will probably also work since the referenced (ASE) system tables (`sysobjects`, `syscolumns`) also exist in SQL Anywhere/IQ products as a (partial) attempt to provide (ASE) T-SQL compatibility.

---

Assuming this is Sybase ASE then a quick join between `sysobjects` and `syscolumns` should suffice:

```
select  c.name
from    dbo.sysobjects o
join    dbo.syscolumns c
on      o.id = c.id
and     o.type in ('U','S')            -- 'U'ser or 'S'ystem table
where   o.name = '<table_name>'
and     c.name like '%<portion_of_column_name>%'
```

For example, let's say we want to find all columns in the `sysobjects` table where the column name contains the string `'trig'`:

```
select  c.name
from    dbo.sysobjects o
join    dbo.syscolumns c
on      o.id = c.id
and     o.type in ('U','S')
where   o.name = 'sysobjects'
and     c.name like '%trig%'
order by 1
go

 ----------
 deltrig
 instrig
 seltrig
 updtrig
```

Comment: @markp_fuso Thanks. When I tried the first two queries you listed, like `select  c.column_name
from    SYS.SYSTABLE t
join    SYS.SYSCOLUMN c
on      t.table_id = c.table_id
where   t.table_name = 'employees'
and     c.column_name like '%income%'` I received no results. However, I know that the table `employees` has a column called `income`. Could there be a reason for this?

Comment: And `syscolumns` in query 3 and 4 result in an error `Sybase Database Error: Table name 'syscolumns' is ambiguous`

Comment: re: first comment (`employees/income` == 0 rows), I'm wondering if IQ (and SQLAnywhere) capitalize the table names in `SYSCOLUMN` (akin to what Oracle does)? what do you get if you run `select table_name from SYS.SYSTABLE order by 1`? do you see `employee` or `EMPLOYEE`?; re: second comment (`syscolumns` == ambiguous) ... ah, yeah, looks like 2 tables/views with same name of `syscolumns` == `SYSCOLUMNS` so there would be a need to preface with the owner; per the docs I'm guessing the owner for the T-SQL compatibility`syscolumns` is `dbo` - I've updated the question accordingly - try that?

Comment: the metadata has to be in there so what I'd try ... `select creator,tname from SYS.SYSCOLUMNS order by 2,1` and review the list to verify the spelling/capitalization of the creator and table name; once you find the records you want then add `cname` to the select/project list and add a `where` clause for the desired row, then verify the column spelling/capitalization